# Is there any way to inject service dependencies in angular 8 test with real dependencies (not fake or mocked)?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular8

I have a service that I wanted to test.

```
MyService.ts
...
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class MyService {
    constructor(
        private readonly _apisService: ApisService,
        private readonly _urlService: UrlService
    ) {}
...
```

This service have 2 dependencies. The **ApiService** have 3 dependencies and this list goes on. each of 3 dependencies have their own dependencies and this list goes on.

```
MyService.spec.ts

...
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [MyService, UrlService, ApisService]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));
...
```

but i get error

```
StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ApisService -> HttpClient]
```

I just want to test this service with real data (not the mocked or fake data) and it is difficult to mock all dependencies.

I want to test **MyService** with real service **without mocking or faking** with all of its dependencies and inject these dependencies in my test without dealing with each one?

Answer (score 0):

add HttpClientTestingModule to imports

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule
   ],
   providers: [TournamentsService, UrlService, ApisService]
}).compileComponents();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @Fedor

Its not just the HTTP module, There are lot of dependencies of ApiService. I do not want to mock or fake its dependencies.

I do not want to test myservice with fake/mocked classes, I want to test myservice with real classes and dependencies.

Comment: Do you want to fully simulate the behavior of the application, and send requests to the server?

Comment: Yes. I want to fully simulate the behavior of application.

Comment: Check E2E tests, for example: [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/)

Comment: I'll use that. But currently I want to test if **MyServices** works as expected and returns data in expected format

Comment: You need the right tool for the right job.  Jasmine (as used by default with the .spec file set up by the Angular CLI) is the tool for unit testing, and with it you mock services, do NOT making backend calls, etc.  Protractor, as suggested by @FedorSaenko above, is the right tool for testing with the real classes and sending requests to the backend.